# iPhone USB tether to VM OS, interface not found

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, freebsd, tethering, freebsd-ports

I am running FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE-p6 as a VM in a Debian 8 (Jessie) hypervisor.

I have passed the USB through the hypervisor, so FreeBSD sees the iPhone USB connection.

However, the FreeBSD VM should add a new interface name ue0, which is not happening.

I installed the FreeBSD kernel module if_ipheth.ko, which is running.

## usbconfig outputs:

```
ugen1.1: <Intel UHCI root HUB> at usbus1, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen0.1: <Intel UHCI root HUB> at usbus0, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen3.1: <Intel UHCI root HUB> at usbus3, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen2.1: <Intel UHCI root HUB> at usbus2, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen4.1: <Intel EHCI root HUB> at usbus4, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen0.2: <QEMU QEMU USB Tablet> at usbus0, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=ON (100mA)
ugen4.2: <Apple Inc. iPhone> at usbus4, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=ON (500mA)
```

Any assistance please?

Comment: The guest is using the network connection of the host machine. Tether the phone to the Host Machine and then the guest machine will get the internet from the Host Machine. Make sure you are using NAT networking for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a tutorial on how to do it that is now present in the newest version of the ipheth(4) manual page (on FreeBSD 13.0):

The following example shows how to manually configure network access on a device that is not automatically recognized.

First, load the driver and find out the unit and the address of the USB Apple device:

```
# kldload ipheth
# usbconfig | grep Apple
ugen0.2: <Apple Inc. iPhone> at usbus0, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=ON (500mA)
```

In this example, the unit and the address of the device is 0.2 (“ugen0.2”), and its configuration index is 0 (“cfg=0”).

Secondly, check what other configurations are available for the device:

```
# usbconfig 0.2 dump_all_config_desc | awk '/^ Conf/{print} /iConf/{print}'
 Configuration index 0
    iConfiguration = 0x0005  <PTP>
 Configuration index 1
    iConfiguration = 0x0006  <iPod USB Interface>
 Configuration index 2
    iConfiguration = 0x0007  <PTP + Apple Mobile Device>
 Configuration index 3
    iConfiguration = 0x0008  <PTP + Apple Mobile Device + Apple USB Ethernet>
```

In this example, there are 4 different configurations available.  The configuration with index 3 seems to be related to Ethernet.  It is time to configure the device:

```
# usbconfig 0.2 set_config 3
# usbconfig | grep 'Apple.*cfg=3'
ugen0.2: <Apple Inc. iPhone> at usbus0, cfg=3 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=ON (500mA)
```

At this point the Apple device should ask whether the FreeBSD machine can be trusted (“Mobile Data” has to be on).

A new `ue` USB Ethernet interface should become available:

```
# dmesg | grep 'ue[0-9]'
ue0: <USB Ethernet> on ipheth0
ue0: bpf attached
ue0: Ethernet address: 4e:7c:5f:2c:5f:7a
```

At this point it might be necessary to run usbmuxd(1) (available in ports(7) at comms/usbmuxd):

```
# usbmuxd --enable-exit --foreground --user root --verbose
```

Now it is time to configure the network interface:

```
# sysrc ifconfig_ue0="SYNCDHCP"
ifconfig_ue0:  -> SYNCDHCP
# service netif restart ue0
```

That is it.  The machine should now be connected to the network via USB tethering.